# Should a input object be cloned if it is the return value?

Tags: c#, clone, return-value

when you have a method such as

```
public static T[] GetZeroArrayIfNot<T>(this T[] array)
{
   if (array == null)
   {
     throw new ArgumentNullException("array");
   }
   else if (array.Length == 0)
   {
       return //array or (array.Clone() as T[])?
   }
   return new T[0];
}
```

or something along the lines of

```
public static int HundredOrLess(int num)
{
    if (num <= 100)
    {
        return //num or ((int num2 = num) => (return num2)) doubt this one matters.
    }
    return 100;
}
```

or

```
public static List<T> ReturnItself<T>(List<T> list)
{
   return //list or (list.Clone() as List<T>);
}
```

if the input is being returned, sins nothing changed, can it be returned just as itself or, should it be cloned and returned as the return type?

Comment: It depends on the requirement, do you want to clone the array (and it's objects) or would you like to change the existing array?

Comment: Who knows. Depends on the kind of logic/purpose of your method. Don't ask us, ask yourself ;-)

Comment: So then i guess it doesn't matter. So, if you wrote something like `byte[] edited = non_edited.RemoveFirstElement();` it wont matter, i thought that `edited` would basically get `non_edited`'s ptr so `edited` will basically BE `non_edited`? But then, when would you use clone, only in scenarios like `byte[] copy =  non_edited.Clone();`?

Comment: It doesn't matter if you return the pointer on an array with zero elements, since to add an element you'd have to create a new array, so there is no way modifying one would impact the other one. If this were a `List<T>`, it would be a different story.

Comment: @RufusL and if it were a List<T>, or a Int32 (which wasn't changed), now i see that i used a pretty bad example.

Comment: The name of the method `RemoveFirstElement` implies that the input should have at least one element, and if not, an exception should be thrown. Otherwise you should change the name of the method to reflect the actual functionality. And then I bet it will be quite obvious what to do with the cloning issue. 

Comment: @TheodorZoulias i don't understand why people take this so literally, its a EXAMPLE not a actual method, its just context to the question, i would have assumed that somebody on this forum would have said `Oh, he probably means in any scenarios and not just this 1 array scenarios`, but i guess not.

Comment: If the example is flawed, then please provide a better example. If you can't think of a better example, then what are we talking about?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias i updated the OP, hope that clears it up. If not, let me know and i will gladly add more examples and info.

Comment: Software developers tend to take things literally. It might be just an example, but the answer for this example could be different from the answer for a different example.

Answer (score 2):

Since your method signature is this:

```
public static T[] RemoveFirstElement<T>(this T[] array)
```

I would assume that this would always return a *new* array. Because you would always have to write:

```
var myArray = SomeArray.RemoveFirstElement();
```

You would not expect that `myArray` would now be pointing to exactly the same object as `SomeArray`. If you wanted it to always operate on the existing array, your method signature would be:

```
public static void RemoveFirstElement<T>(this T[] array)
```

So that writing:

```
var myArray = SomeArray.RemoveFirstElement();
```

Would result in a compile-time error. And it would be apparent that seeing:

```
SomeArray.RemoveFirstElement();
```

Would be operating in-place.

Answer (score 0):

An array with zero length is immutable, so it can be returned safely without cloning.

To remove an element from a non-empty array, anyway it needs to be cloned because the length of array cannot be changed.

```
public static T[] RemoveFirstElement<T>(this T[] array)
{
   if (array == null)
   {
     throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(array));
   }
   else if (array.Length == 0)
   {
       return array;
   }
   else
   {
       return array.Skip(1).ToArray();
   }
}
```

Comment: ok, so what if it was something else like a method to check if a value is greated than 100 and if it is then 100 is returned then what if the input is less than or equal to 100, can it itself be returned?

Comment: The case of returning a value (like an `int`) is also different because an array is a reference type, so returning the original vs. returning a clone are potentially different things. With value types it doesn't matter at all. Even if you "return" the argument you're not really returning the input - you're returning a new `int` with the same value as the input.

Comment: @ScottHannen THANK YOU, now that's the answer i was looking for, thank you for clearing this up for me.

Comment: I appreciate that, but to split hairs, I only provided a comment, not an answer. (More being literal.)

Comment: @ScottHannen regardless, thanks a lot. Also i think you should be able to submit that comment as a answer, sins i edited the question and it's more "well rounded".

Answer (score 0):

This is my opinion regarding the new examples:

```
public static T[] GetZeroArrayIfNot<T>(this T[] array)
{
    if (array == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("array");
    }
    else if (array.Length == 0)
    {
        return array;
        // because the name of the method implies that a zero-length array
        // should be treated differently than a non-zero-length array
    }
    return new T[0];
}

public static int HundredOrLess(int num)
{
    if (num <= 100)
    {
        return num;
        // It doesn't matter. The caller is not affected either way
        // because num is an immutable value type passed by value
    }
    return 100;
}

public static List<T> ReturnItself<T>(List<T> list)
{
    return list; // Because the method name says so
}
```